# Get multiple elements from list by indices in constant time

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8

What is the best way to get multiple elements from a list by their indices in constant time?

If I've an array:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");
list.add("d");
list.add("e");
```

And I've an list/array with indices:

```
List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
indices.add(0);
indices.add(2);
indices.add(3);
```

How can I get a,c,d in constant time?
I need something like this:

```
List<String> filtered = list.filterByIndex(indices);
filtered.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.print(x));
// output:"acd"
```

**UPDATE:**
The printing of the items doesn't have to be in constant time of course, only the collecting of items. The code above of printing the elements is just for demonstrating purposes only.

Comment: If somebody votes down this question, please leave a comment what's the reason of that...

Comment: `for (Integer index : indices) { System.out.println(list.get(index)); }` ?

Comment: @JB Nizet I don't think that runs in constant time.

Comment: it's O(N), where N is the size of the indices list. You can't possibly beat that.

Comment: Putting N elements in a list is at least `O(N)`, whichever way you're looking at it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest:

```
    List<String> filtered = indices.stream()
            .map(list::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result is the desired:

```
[a, c, d]
```

Assuming the list has constant-time access (as an `ArrayList` has), this runs in time that is linear in the number of elements requested (length of `indices`), but does not increase with the length of the list `list`. As has been discussed in comments, this is the best we can do.

Edit: Honestly I don’t know whether the collecting step above is in linear time in the number of collected elements. Possibly extensions of list capacity cost time, and probably this doesn’t take more than linear time. If we need to be sure, we need to collect this way instead:

```
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<>(indices.size())));
```

This makes sure a list with appropriate capacity is allocated from the outset so no extensions will be needed.

Answer (score 3):

To create a list:

```
List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
indices.forEach(index -> filtered.add(list.get(index)));

System.out.println(filtered);
```

Stream and map solution

```
List<String> filtered = indices.stream()
        .map(index -> list.get(index))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

If you need only string you can do it with StringBuilder

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuffer();
indices.forEach(index -> sb.append(list.get(index)));

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you, but my example code used Strings because it's easy to demonstrate.. I want to collect generic types.
(sry, my mistake)

Comment: Updated answer with case with list

Answer (score 1):

You might do something like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, list.size())
       .boxed()
       .filter(indices::contains)
       .map(list::get)
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This will take linear time in the length of the list, right?

Comment: How could I be sure, that your code runs in constant time, and the runtime is independent from lengths of any of the lists?

Comment: @user1802693 that's completely impossible. If you need to print N things, the time will at least be proportional to N.

Comment: It's not necessary to print the items.. I have to only collect them. The print in the example code was just for demonstrating purposes.

Comment: If you don't need to do anything with the N items you get, then don't do anything (i.e. don't get them), and it will be constant time.